# Catkin cannot find gtest

Tags: googletest, ros, catkin

Since yesterday none of my packages containing tests build. Catkin complains it cannot find gtest when using catkin_add_gtests(), since GTEST_FOUND is FALSE. You can see this in the error msg below, with the custom output I added to my CMakeLists. Up to yesterday, GTEST_FOUND was TRUE when catkin_add_gtests() was called.

This is the error I always get. In this case I'm trying to build a mockup package on a clean catkin workspace:

```
Errors     << silly_pkg:cmake /home/paco/catkin_ws2/logs/silly_pkg/build.cmake.002.log                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
Re-run cmake no build system arguments
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/paco/catkin_ws2/devel/.private/silly_pkg
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/paco/catkin_ws2/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic
-- This workspace overlays: /home/paco/catkin_ws2/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/paco/catkin_ws2/build/silly_pkg/test_results
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.11
-- GTEST_FOUND: FALSE
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/test/gtest.cmake:149 (message):
  skipping gtest 'test_silly_pkg' in project 'silly_pkg' because gtest was
  not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/test/gtest.cmake:79 (_catkin_add_executable_with_google_test)
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/test/gtest.cmake:28 (_catkin_add_google_test)
  CMakeLists.txt:28 (catkin_add_gtest)


CMake Error at /home/paco/catkin_ws2/src/silly_pkg/CMakeLists.txt:33 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "test_silly_pkg" which is not
  built by this project.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/paco/catkin_ws2/build/silly_pkg/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/paco/catkin_ws2/build/silly_pkg/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
cd /home/paco/catkin_ws2/build/silly_pkg; catkin build --get-env silly_pkg | catkin env -si  /usr/bin/cmake /home/paco/catkin_ws2/src/silly_pkg --no-warn-unused-cli -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/paco/catkin_ws2/devel/.private/silly_pkg -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/paco/catkin_ws2/install; cd -
```

I am using catkin 0.7.11, libgtest-dev 1.7.0 and cmake 3.5.1. I use ROS Kinetic with Ubuntu 16.04. The only thing I did yesterday was reinstalling ROS Kinetic, but the package versions are exactly the same. Did anybody have this problem? Do you have any ideas on what could be happening?

EDIT 3/09/18:

By comparing with a functional catkin+gtest workspace in a different computer, I found out that the main difference is in the results of `/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/test/gtest.cmake`. In the functional workspace, [line 292](https://github.com/ros/catkin/blob/kinetic-devel/cmake/test/gtest.cmake#L292) evaluates to TRUE (gtest/gmock is not a target) while in my workspace it evaluates to FALSE. This is because in my workspace running `find_package(GMock QUIET)` (line 287) sets gmock and gtest as imported targets, which does not happen in the other computer. Why is this different?

Thanks TikO for your help!

Comment: If you have found a solution, please add an answer to your own question below. Questions are not supposed to have an answer embedded in them, nor should they have a "(SOLVED)" written on them. You can instead use the check mark button to annotate an answer which was the most useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you wrote that cmake does not find the libraries and that you have reinstalled Kinetic, I assume that you have a freshly installed machine or wiped out gtest libraries by accident.
If you install `libgtest-dev`, you only get the sources which you need to build and install like this:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtest-dev
mkdir /tmp/gtest_build && cd /tmp/gtest_build
cmake /usr/src/gtest
make
#copy or symlink libgtest.a and ligtest_main.a to /usr/lib folder
sudo cp *.a /usr/lib
```

After this routine, you should be able to build again without cmake complaining.

***Optional***

If you have limited rights on your machine and you are not allowed to install the libraries in that way, just copy them into some home folder like

```
mkdir ~/lib && cp *.a ~/lib
```

But be aware of the fact, that you have to call catkin in the following way:

```
LIBRARY_PATH=~/lib GTEST_ROOT=~/lib catkin_make
```

`LIBRARY_PATH` tells the linker where to find the libraries, while `GTEST_ROOT` gives cmake the location hints for it's checks.

*Reference*: https://github.com/tik0/gtest_ros_example

Comment: Thanks! I think this would be the solution if I needed to link against the libraries. But, as far as I know, catkin_add_gtests() finds the files in /usr/src and /usr/include to compile gtest with your catkin packages. This is done in order to compile your tests with the same options as your code, according to the libgtest README.

Comment: I tried it and, as expected, cmake complains that it cannot build gtest as an imported library because  "because another target
  with the same name already exists".

Comment: Ok, got you. Could you just upload your `CMakeLists.txt` or the project? The point is, that `find_package(GTest REQUIRED)` is will return FALSE when it does not find the pre-built libraries in your system folders. Thus it does not correlate with your error. Could it be, that some sub-project tries to find gtest via `find_package`?

Comment: Exactly, I am afraid that find_package is the origin of the problem. See the latest question update.

Comment: I assume that both systems use different find-package modules for either gmock or gtest (system-wide vs ROS-internals). Run cmake in debug mode (e.g. `-Wdev`, `--debug-output` and `--trace`) and compare both outputs. It could also help to investigate both environments via `env`.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION FOUND

gmock and gtest were being set to imported target because the suggested manual compilation of libgtest had created a FindGMock.cmake file inside /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules. This file was being called by the find(GMock QUIET) 
in catkin_add_gtests(), therefore setting the imported target. Just deleting FindGMock.cmake solved the issue.